# Footer won't stay at bottom

Tags: html, css

I have not been able to get any of the solutions to work.

The footer keeps on leaving a gap at the bottom of this [page](http://vs.avischulman.com/?page_id=76)

The footer leaves a gap of white space.

I have tried

```
#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

and it seems to make it worse...

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
still can't get it to work. tried setting the height of the body and wrapper. tried all code below. and it just ends up overlapping

Comment: "bottom: 0" refers to the bottom of the relevant parent element. Check your html, body and wrapper height.

Comment: agree, from a first look i can say that all of your external div havo no dimension...try to fix this and implements some heights and width

Comment: It's a responsive website not sure why I would need to define something that should have no definiton

Comment: I've tried setting the hieght of my wrapper and it seems to make no difference...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
}
```

I believe that is what you are after. Position absolute relates to the document whereas position fixed relates to the screen view.

**EDIT**

Assuming your footer has a height of 50px say, you need to add a margin to an element that is above the footer in the DOM, some sort of wrapper ideally that appears on every page of your site (this makes the most sense structurally.

Even if you add this element yourself assuming you have access to a template.

So it could look something like this:

```
<header></header>
<div class="content">
  //wrap all of your main content block here
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Then for the css add `margin-bottom:70px` to the `.content` wrapper

Comment: The problem is with small screens it will overlap content with that code

Comment: Yes the trick is to add some margin or padding to the main content block, that is at least the height of your footer. If you know the exact height, you can do it with css.

Comment: I set the height of the footer to `.footer-wrap {
  height: 5em;
}`

Comment: I set the content padding-bottom to 5em and still shows white space

Comment: Problem with bottom margin is on screens higher then mine the white space prevails.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I suggest though that there may be other issues with your code potentially. This is why jsfiddle is useful, you can just isolate the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
#footer-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I don't think you want to use position: fixed because if your page were to get any taller (to the point that vertical scrolling was required), the footer would stay attached to the bottom of the page wherever you went. I think what you want is this:

```
<style>
   .footer-wrap{position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;}
   body{overflow: hidden;}
</style>
```

You need to add the overflow: hidden on the body because the 100% width on the footer will create a horizontal scroll.

Comment: Close but it will overlap content on smaller screens

Answer (score 0):

The footer is an automatically defined element in HTML5 you basic page should look like this and everything should be  place

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Place title here</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<header>
  
  </header>
  
<nav>
  
  </nav>
  
<main>
  
  </main>
  
<footer>
  
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

A good CSS configuration for each could be something like

```css
<style>
header {
  background-color:place color here;
  }


nav {
  background-color:place color here;
  }

main {
  background-color:place color here;
  }


footer {
  background-color:place color here;
  }
</style>
```

NOTE:Footer and header should be same color as the body color makes page more presentable

Comment: Well i'm just going off the design given to me to code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by setting a bottom margin in the post

```
article.post-72.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry {
  margin-bottom: 124px!important;
}
```

and adding some height and overflow the the footer

```
.footer-wrap {
  height: 115px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This question could have been greatly improved via the use of a jsfiddle. But adding the bottom margin was my recommendation.

Comment: jsfiddle would not have worked. but it can't hold a wordpress site. But only a very small snippet of code.

Comment: And you did recommend margin or padding. Just not to what kind of margin or padding or to what element. So I wanted to post my answer with the specifics. Thank you! p.s. since pages have diff content you must apply the fix per page.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late, but I stumbled upon this today and I know the solution for it.

Just use: `display:flex;`

This'll make this white space vanish. Hope this helps someone.